# How to average certain values in a range of dates in excel

Tags: excel, average

A column are dates, B column are values. There might be 10 values in column B which corresponding to the same dates in column A. On the next day, there might be 14 values in column B corresponding to the next date in column A. I would like to average values in column B on the same date and I have over thousands of lines. Any suggestion of how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a PivotTable with dates for ROWS and Average of value for Σ VALUES:

[image: SO26127614 example]

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's sigma values?

Answer (score 0):

[AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Create Column C with only unique dates for A.

In Column D, formula should be: `=AVERAGEIF(A$1:A$100, C1, $B1:B$100)`

Adjust row numbers as necessary for A and B.

Comment: @XinQiao [How to create a list of unique values](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx).